# Searching for Strings

Tags: shell, scripting

I would like to have a shell script that searches two files and returns a list of strings:

File A contains just a list of unique alphanumeric strings, one per line, like this:

```
accc_34343
GH_HF_223232
cwww_34343
jej_222
```

File B contains a list of SOME of those strings (some times more than once), and a second column of infomation, like this:

```
accc_34343 dog
accc_34343 cat
jej_222 cat
jej_222 horse
```

I would like to create a third file that contains a list of the strings from File A that are NOT in File B.

I've tried using some loops with grep -v, but that doesn't work. So, in the above example, the new file would have this as it's contents:

```
GH_HF_223232
cwww_34343
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
grep -v -f <(awk '{print $1}' file_b) file_a > file_c
```

**Explanation:**

- `grep -v` : Use `-v` option to `grep` to invert the matching
- `-f` : Use `-f` option to `grep` to specify that the patterns are from file
- `<(awk '{print $1}' file_b)`: The `<(awk '{print $1}' file_b)` is to simply extract the first column values from `file_b` without using a temp file; the `<( ... )` syntax is [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).
- `file_a` : Tell `grep` that the file to be searched is `file_a`
- `> file_c` : Output to be written to `file_c`

Comment: Dear Sampson-Chen, this worked wonderfully. In files with a few thousand entries, the processing time was less than 10 seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) is used to find intersections and differences between files:

```
comm -23 <(sort fileA) <(cut -d' ' -f1 fileB | sort -u)
```

result:

```
GH_HF_223232
cwww_34343
```

I assume your shell is bash/zsh/ksh

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($1 in a)' fileA fileB
```

check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html)